# Sitecore create package from .Net Visual Studio

Tags: package, sitecore

I need to create a Sitecore package from my visual studio project.  Can someone shed some light on this?  I don't want to install my code in all instances of my site so i want to install it using the Sitecore Package Installer

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sitecore Rocks to create package in Visual Studio. There is a tutorial here https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/trevor_campbell/posts/28-days-of-sitecore-rocks-package-creation

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  i'll give it a try.

Comment: This is a great link for creating a package of content in SItecore.  Is there something that shows how to package "DLL's" for a Sitecore .Net solution?  I am modifying a source solution downloaded from the Marketplace. Thanks,